# Create TCP Packet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, packet

I'm sending data to an extremely old system via TCP. I need to send 2000 bytes in one packet, and I need it not to be split up (what happens when I write out 2000 bytes via a socket).

While, yes, I shouldn't have to care about this at an application level -- I in fact do care about this, because I have no other options on the older system, everything MUST be received in a single packet.

Is there something less terrible than calling netcat?

Comment: Are you sure you're not sending this packet UDP? TCP is a connection-based protocol, meaning it establishes a link between the two computers, and the data transmission should be treated as a stream. Trying to send a single packet over TCP is contradictory.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that much -- it's not contradictory to send a single packet over TCP -- the receiver will be receiving a stream of these over time, but I was hoping to control the fragmentation of the data into the packets sent (given the archaic stack on the receiving end).

Comment: You are probably confusing *tcp segmentation* and *ip fragmentation*. TCP tries very hard to optimize the former to avoid the later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are on a link with [jumbo frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame) the usual [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) on the [ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) is 1500. Subtract [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) (20 bytes) and [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) headers (at least 20 bytes). So no luck with 2000 bytes in a single packet.